# Setting the focus in a datagridview in windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that accepts a list(of myObject) as a datasource. I want to add a new row to the datagrid to add to the database. I get this done by getting the list... adding a blank myObject to the list and then reseting the datasource. I now want to set the focus to the second cell in the new row.

To CLARIFY i am trying to set the focus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the focus to a specific cell in a row but only if the SelectionMode on the DataGridView is set to CellSelect. If it is, simply do the following:

```
dataGridView.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[columnNumber].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, you should be able to set the

```
Me.dataEvidence.SelectedRows
```

property to the row you want selected.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio **2012** (vb.NET **Framework 4.50**), you can set the focus on any desired cell of a DataGridView control.

Try This:

```
Sub Whatever()

    ' all above code

    DataGridView1.Focus()
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y)       'x is your desired row number, y is your desired column number

    ' all below code

End Sub
```

Okay, that works for me. I hope that it works for you, too.